# Foucault pendulum before Foucault: how do they explain it?

Tags: alternate-history, outdated-science

[Foucault pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) is a good experiment to prove Earth rotation

> The Foucault pendulum or Foucault's pendulum is a simple device named after French physicist Léon Foucault and conceived as an experiment to demonstrate the Earth's rotation. The pendulum was introduced in 1851 and was the first experiment to give simple, direct evidence of the Earth's rotation.

In an alternate history which my world is following, let's say that Galileo firstly performed this experiment while playing with pendulum. When reporting about his findings, a debate on the explanation of the phenomena ensues, and Galileian physics probably didn't have the instruments to fully describe it.

How would the phenomena be tentatively explained in the context of [Aristotelian physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotelian_physics) or [Scholasticim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism#Scholastic_method)?

Comment: "How would the phenomena be tentatively explained in the context of Aristotelian physics" Witchcraft, burn him at the stake. Oh, wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Aristotle was many things, but a physicist he wasn't. Yes, he did write a book titled *Physicê acroasis*, and yes, we do traditionally translate its title as *Physics*, but that just a traditional mistranslation. The correct translation of the title would be *Lecture about nature* -- the Greek word *physis* means origin or nature.

  - First, we should understand that "Aristotelian physics" is a very loose and imprecise term by which we generally understand ancient and medieval physics.
  - Second, ancient and medieval physics simply dd not have **any** framework for calculating the motion of bodies in response to forces. Kinematics, yes. Statics, yes. Dynamics, no.
  - As for the scholastics, they supremely ignored physics altogether, lumping it in the inchoate mass called natural philosophy.
- Now, as we said, ancient and medieval physics had an excellent understanding of kinematics; and Earth's rotation around its axis is kinematically equivalent to the first motion of the celestial sphere in the Ptolemaic model.

  (For the readers who went to school after Ptolemy's cosmological model was replaced with this new-fangled Keplerian model, the "first motion" of the celestial sphere is the rotation which is responsible the rising and setting of the stars and planets, including the sun and the moon.)
- So that, as far as ancient and medieval natural philosphers would have been concerned, it would simply be the case that the nature of pendulums makes them preserve the orientation of the plane of oscillation relative to the celestial sphere.
- Which is actually correct. Except of course that in Newtonian physics we believe that the celestial sphere is immobile...
- But this doesn't change the fact that ancient or medieval physics was simply incapable of explaining the most striking property of pendulums, namely their property of having a period of oscillation independent of the amplitude of oscillation.

Comment: +1. But, if they "Dynamics, no.", they could not have explained the precession and the dependence with sin(latitude) of the period. BTW, Galileo and his contemporaries experimented with what will be named Foucault pendulum (Vicenzo Viviani), and dropping weight from high towers or shooting cannonballs vertically. See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338347971_Before_Foucault_The_Proofs_of_the_Earth%27s_Rotation)